# Best Workaround for missing Login-As on Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: mobile, debugging, user-management, grant-login-access

As an unfortunate, there seems to be still no Login-As for Admins and Devs to test, review and debug the Salesforce Mobile app impersonated as an other user.

This is extremely important but since 2014 it is only an "idea": https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYsyUAF/salesforce1-admin-login-as-another-user

[image]

We have lots of users, lots of profiles and it is a pain in the ass to reproduce and support any user feedback. Simply because this crucial function is missing. I want to zoom-in to the most painful scenario where a repro is ONLY possible as a certain user (e.g. caused by complex sharing and permission scenario) and where due to of incomplete or outdate data, a sandbox is not usable for such repro either.

Now I'm interested on how you deal with this? Is there any workaround better than temporarily taking over the user who needs complex support, to login with new credentials as admin? It is a huge waste of time and error-prone to adjust email, password, MFA just to repro a feedback and later to provide access back to the real user. During the time required for repro and support, the user can not easily use the service.

Any better workaround is highly appreciated.